# Problem with building the project on Vite

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite

After I assembled the project, Vite created copies of my react ts components with a js extension and when I try to change the component in the browser, nothing changes. Now it only links to JS files. How can I make sure that after building the project it can be used as before and that when building the files are downloaded to the dist folder and not src?

This is what my components folder looks like after assembly.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWuXq.jpg)

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "rosem",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build ",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "localforage": "^1.10.0",
    "match-sorter": "^6.3.1",
    "qs": "^6.11.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.1",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "sort-by": "^1.2.0",
    "swiper": "^11.0.5"
  },
   "devDependencies": {
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.11",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.21.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.21.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "vite": "^5.0.8"
  }
  }
```

tsconfig.json

```
  {
   "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "esnext",
     "module": "esnext",
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "jsx": "react",
     "strict": true,
     "esModuleInterop": true,
     "skipLibCheck": true,
     "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "include": ["src"]
    }
```

I tried to do

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
    import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh'
    import eslintPlugin from 'vite-plugin-eslint'
    export default defineConfig({
        plugins: [reactRefresh(), eslintPlugin({ cache: false })],
        root: 'src',
        build: {
            outDir: '../dist'
        }
    })
```